# Expansion on given string according to number * contents of the parentheses

Tags: java, string, algorithm, stringbuilder, expansion

I am trying to take a given string and when there is a number before parentheses then what's inside the parentheses gets repeated that number of times. I thought about using StringBuilder and built this function but I'm not sure how to get the inside of the parentheses repeated.
example- 3(ab) - result would be ababab , example- 3(b(2(c))) result would be bccbccbcc
in the function I built here it repeats the parentheses and not the contents of the parentheses.

```
  public static String solve(String s){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int repeat = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            repeat = repeat * 10 + Character.getNumericValue(c);
        } else {
            while (repeat > 0) {
                sb.append(c);
                repeat--;
            }
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The somewhat tricky part here is finding the matching paranthesis. The easiest approach would probably be to use multiple passes, where each pass only replaces parts that have no opening paranthesis before the next closing paranthesis. You can stop when there are no more parantheses left, or you find a syntax error (e.g. only a single parantheses left)

Comment: Is the number in front of the parentheses always a single digit, or is `12(b)` also a valid input? And can numbers also appear somewhere else than in front of a parenthesis; e.g. `3(a4b)`?

Comment: Input will consist of only lowercase letters and numbers (1 to 9) in valid parenthesis. There will be no letters or numbers after the last closing parenthesis.

Comment: Just for context, the more general task is called parsing, or building a [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) or [syntax tree (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). There are libraries for that, but they are probably overkill for your relatively simple syntax. Building a tree structure can allow you to do this in a single pass. (You don't need to acutally create the tree, but it can help to think about a recursive approach).

Comment: What about letters in front of parentheses like your second example: `3(b(2(c)))` `=>` `3(b(cc))` ?

Comment: So if the input is `3(b(2(c)x))` then would the output be `bccxbccxbccx` ?

Comment: This is a problem that *screams* recursion. You can solve it without, but the natural solution is recursive.

Comment: @abra yes, correct

Comment: @etritrean yes, i suppose you do a while loop to make sure you get all the numbers before a  parentheses then multiply the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same answer as [@SerialLazers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64874016/4668606), but in java and with a bit of debugging-output to see how the code behaves:

```
public static String solve(String s)
{
    Stack<Integer> countStack = new Stack<>();   // stack for counting
    Stack<StringBuilder> stubs = new Stack<>();  // stack for parts of the string that were processed
    stubs.push(new StringBuilder());
    
    int count = 0;
    for(char c : s.toCharArray())
    {
        System.out.println(Character.toString(c) + "   " + count + "   " + countStack + stubs);
        
        if(Character.isDigit(c))
        {
            // part of a count (assumes digits are never part of the actual output-string)
            count = count * 10 + (c - '0');
        }
        else if(c == '(')
        {
            // encountered the start of a new repeated group
            if(count == 0)
                // no count specified, assume a count of one
                countStack.push(1);
            else
                // push the count for this group
                countStack.push(count);

            // push a new stringbuilder that will contain the new group
            stubs.push(new StringBuilder());
            count = 0;  // reset count
        }
        else if(c == ')')
        {
            // group terminated => repeat n times and append to new group one above
            String tmp = stubs.pop().toString();
            int ct = countStack.pop();
            
            for(int i = 0; i < ct; i++)
                stubs.peek().append(tmp);
        }
        else
        {
            // just a normal character, append to topmost group
            stubs.peek().append(c);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    
    // if the string was valid there's only the output-string left on the stubs-list
    return stubs.peek().toString();
}
```

Output:

```
3   0   [][]
(   3   [][]
b   0   [3][, ]
(   0   [3][, b]
2   0   [3, 1][, b, ]
(   2   [3, 1][, b, ]
c   0   [3, 1, 2][, b, , ]
)   0   [3, 1, 2][, b, , c]
)   0   [3, 1][, b, cc]
)   0   [3][, bcc]
```

Returns:

```
bccbccbcc
```

Comment: Creating lots of new string builders in this way is cargo cult programming; it’s actually *less* efficient than using string concatenation.

Comment: ok. i tried this out, but in this example expected:<opwzptptpt[zptptpt]> but was:<opwzptptpt[]> is there a way that it doesn't remove the contents of [] i think its from the pop functions which you used

Comment: given: 4(1(5b(n(j)))) output: bnjbnjbnjbnj expected output: bnjbnjbnjbnj[bnjbnjbnjbnjbnjbnjbnjbnjbnjbnjbnjbnjbnjbnjbnjbnj]

Comment: @Paul check above please

Comment: @KonradRudolph well, as usually, the code is rather intended to demonstrate a principle than being the most performant solution. There's quite a few points where this could be optimized, but at least IMO readability is preferable over performance

Comment: @rokkcrow how is that even a valid input? There's no parenthesis after the 5. Would probably be worthwhile putting the actual grammar-rules into the question

Comment: @Paul “readability is preferable over performance” — I totally agree, but that’s *yet more reason* to use `String` instead of `StringBuilder` here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think so. With `StringBuilder` we can work directly on the stack instead of pushing and popping strings every iteration. In addition I'm not quite sure that using `String` actually improves performance considering that we need to append a char to the topmost string of the stack quite a few times

Comment: @Paul Concatenation of small strings is fairly efficient. String builders only really make sense for *long* strings, they have a nontrivial overhead. That said, the pushing/popping argument is true, I had overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is naturally recursive. Preserving the approach you’ve started, you could write something like the following. In real code, I’d probably favour an approach that separated tokenisation and parsing, meaning I would do two separate passes: the first to transform the input string into tokens, and the second to produce output from the token stream.

```java
public static Pair<String, Integer> solve(String s, int start) {
    int repeat = 0;
    String ret = "";

    for (int i = start; i < s.length(); i++) {
        final char c = s.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            repeat = repeat * 10 + Character.getNumericValue(c);
        } else if (c == '(') {
            final Pair<String, Integer> inner = solve(s, i + 1);
            // At least one repetition, even if no explicit `repeat` given.
            ret += inner.first;
            while (--repeat > 0) {
                ret += inner.first;
            }
            repeat = 0; // Ensure that `repeat` isn’t -1 after the loop.
            i = inner.second;
        } else if (c == ')') {
            return new Pair<>(ret, i);
        } else {
            ret += c;
        }
    }

    return new Pair<>(ret, s.length());
}
```

Converting this code to use a single `StringBuilder` — to avoid redundant string copies — is left as an exercise.

---

The above uses a simple `Pair` helper class. Since Java doesn’t ship with one (*groan*), here’s a very simple implementation that can sit alongside the above code; you can also use JavaFX’s `javafx.util.Pair` or `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` or whatever.

```java
static class Pair<T, U> {
    final T first;
    final U second;

    Pair(T f, U s) {
        first = f;
        second = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried using the import but it seems to give me error- on eclipse

Comment: @rokkcrow What error? And how did you try using it?

Comment: i copied the import and import javafx.util.Pair; before the class and it gives me error and when I put in the code its not one of the import options

Comment: @rokkcrow Again, *what error?* And what Java version are you using? (JavaFX was removed in Java 11, but there are other, straightforward ways of replacing a `Pair` class.)

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE

Comment: no worries, appreciate the help and ill try to do some testing when I have time. thanks again!

Comment: @rokkcrow You still haven’t mentioned the actual error message. Anyway, just replace the import with `static class Pair<T, U> { final T first; final U second; Pair(T f, U s) { first = f; second = s; }}`, and adjust the code to use `first` and `second` instead of `getKey()` and `getValue()`.

Comment: ok. thanks. there isnt a specific error message it just doesn't accept the import

Answer (score 0):

You need a stack to maintain sort of a memory of the operations you need from inner-most to outermost container.

Here is the code in Python:

```
def parenthesis_printer(s):
    L = [""]   # maintains the stack of the string-containers
    N = [1]    # maintains the stack of the print-multiplier needed for the corresponding string-container
    nstr = ""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i].isnumeric():
            nstr += s[i]
        elif s[i] == '(':
            nstr = "1" if len(nstr) == 0 else nstr
            nval = int(nstr)
            N.append(nval)
            L.append("")
            nstr = ""
        elif s[i] == ')':
            nval = N.pop()
            lval = L.pop()
            lstr = "".join([lval for _ in range(nval)])
            L[-1] += lstr
        else:
            L[-1] += s[i]
    return L[-1]

print(parenthesis_printer("3(b(2(c)))"))
```

Output:

```
bccbccbcc
```

Comment: The idea is easily transferrable to Java. The logic remains intact.

Comment: is N and L strings or a string array?

Comment: and where does each loop finish?

Comment: N and L are stacks. N maintains the number-multiplers and L maintains the strings in the corresponding containers

Comment: so the stacks are instead of the stringbuilder?